# Cheapest Raspberrypi (or MCU) power supply with both toggle *and* momentary switches?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, raspberry-pi, npn, pnp

**TL;DR/main question:**

How would one modify [this PCB](https://kitnic.it/boards/github.com/kasbah/push-on-hold-off/) to **add an extra toggle switch** that **does not just abruptly cut the power** to a load and that still allows enough time for a clean shutdown of, i.e, a Raspberry Pi?

That is, **two different buttons** in the above PCB (one momentary, the other latched). I want it to be **all passives, without involving MCUs**.

**Long version, see comments below too:**

Together with a friend we tried to [implement the following schematic we found online after a quick search for "simple raspberry pi on/off latch power supply"](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/on-off-power-controller):

[image]

Then we simulated the above schematic through our [circuits.io breadboard](https://circuits.io/circuits/2435671/edit#breadboard):

[image]

Despite the simulator lagging a bit when pressing the momentary switch, it seems to work fine. This is similar to the simpler circuit that [Dave Jones from EEVblog showcases in his "Soft Latching Power Switch" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Foc9R0dC2iI), which we also implemented in [circuits.io for comparison](https://circuits.io/circuits/2463364-eevblog-soft-latch-power-switch):

[image: EEVblog circuit]

To be clear on what I'm asking, I would like to **add a toggle (physically latched switch)** to the circuits shown above in order to have both types of switches in one circuit.

1. A single push button for soft on/off behavior.
2. A toggle, physically latched, switch that respects shutdown times as in requirement "1" above.

All of it implemented in an analogical manner, [without involving MCU's as featured recently in HackaDay](https://hackaday.com/2016/06/28/raspberry-pi-gets-turned-on/) **and** without 3 switches, which I think is unnecessary flexibility/complexity:

https://www.pi-supply.com/product/pi-supply-raspberry-pi-power-switch/

Comment: Are you setting GPIO4 high in your code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting! There's no code/RPi involved at this stage, but I guess you mean setting that line high? If that's the case, I tried injecting 1V there, no effect :/

Comment: Post a pic of your actual construction - there might be a small non-obvious error somewhere...

Comment: Tried to do right now, but it seems that I need >10 points in reputation to post more than 2 links :_(... let's see if I can over here...: https://ipfs.pics/QmPHV6zBnDbNT2no9ezviChMrBHA95ncf5zkWBndZi4Jwj

Comment: The previous pic was "before", now it's after 2-3 seconds (really sorry for the mess of wires :_/): https://ipfs.pics/QmWPPALFbysGf6vnL3YvCHxhcwuXUGTLaXWHJa8FRSgRo8

Comment: And here's the schematic as interpreted by circuits.io after laying out the components/connections in the bread board: https://ipfs.pics/Qmay1Pw47Wcsqtj4AuHHQVyNCLsQFJkJzYb6gFiP1H6ZDC

Comment: The wire mess isn't very informative. Given that it works in simulation, have you gone round with a multimeter checking that voltages at various points matches that in the simulation? Especially during the 2-3 critical seconds. Is the "auto on / auto off" set correctly? Are you definitely using a momentary switch for the pushbutton?

Comment: Sorry again for the wires, we'll try to arrange it soon so it's clearer. Here's also were it becomes tricky. We are using this dual mosfet SMD IC in our real-world tests: http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/indexerfiles/Datasheets-SW8/DSASW00156661.pdf ... so voltages seem to vary a bit. And in the real world it doesn't even turn on (perhaps bad contact of the wires in the (cheap) bread board?). That is why we switched early into simulation via circuits.io for faster iteration/testing... Yes, the auto-off is set via cap to +5V (auto-off), if switched to GND, it behaves as spec'd (auto-on)...

Comment: ... and yes, the momentary switch is definitely that since very short hold-downs do not power the circuit, but ~500ms ones do power up the circuit. Holding on the mom. switch forever keeps the light turned on always in the simulation, as specified in the original circuit.

Comment: Here's some rep, now please [edit] all of the additional information from your comments into your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone! I cleaned up the board a bit now, please have a look. After the cleanup, the problem is gone but there's another one: **it latches on forever and does not turn off**. Any ideas now that the breadboard is clearer?

Comment: [I just created a breadboard with the EEVBlog circuit](https://circuits.io/circuits/2463364-eevblog-soft-latch-power-switch) referred above and it lights the led/bulb **but it does not turn off when clicking the momentary switch again**. Therefore, unless proven wrong, **I call a bug in the circuits.io simulator!**, bummer!

Comment: Hey people, [I made the small PCB inked above](https://kitnic.it/boards/github.com/kasbah/push-on-hold-off/). I have quite a lot of PCBs left over and I'd be happy to send some to you. 

On the GitHub repo linked from the Kitnic site there is also a LTSpice simulation of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @kasbah! I downloaded and tried LTSpice and I can measure the current and voltages in different points in the circuit... but I don't know how to simulate the dynamics of the S1/SW element (a.k.a pushing the button and seeing how the circuit reacts to that)... any hints on how to do that like in the circuits.io breadboard? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [the simulation I made](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kasbah/push-on-hold-off/master/simulation/push-on-hold-off.asc). I use a voltage controlled switch.

Comment: Sorry kasbah, not sure I know how to use that simulation you made :_( Care to explain a bit?

Comment: There was actually a bug in http://circuits.io. Their support folks are amazing! (edited): """The simulator can display transient RC behavior, but you discovered something we're still working on: simulation of purely analog flip-flops or multivibrators that do not converge. (...) we're eager to fix once we have time. The capacitor that was added to the base of the second NPN changes the time constant of the oscillator, but it is still in essence a multivibrating oscillator.

This blog post includes an oscillating circuit: http://blog.123dapp.com/2014/04/123d-circuits-gets-new-superpowers"""

Comment: Even with your edit, there is no clear, concise question here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Chris, good point. Does it make more sense now with the specific TL;DR's on top? :)